# Trying to figure out if Data is TDES or AES encrypted

Tags: exception, encryption

My problem is that I need to upgrade some encryption of data from a database into AES.

The original Data was TDES encrypted.

So what I did was use TDES to unencrypt, then AES to reencrypt.

My issue is that if for some reason the sql connection dies, or the program dies, or whatever...only part of the DB will be updated.

I tried this:

```
try
{
    plainPassword = DecryptTDES(Convert.ToString(reader[1]));
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainPassword)) 
                        {
                            // Reencrypt plainPassword into AES
                        }
}
catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

DecryptTDES looks like this partially:

```
 using (System.IO.MemoryStream DecryptedStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {                
            using (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream crStream = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(DecryptedStream, cryptoTransform,
                System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                try
                {
                    crStream.Write(cypherTextBArray, 0, cypherTextBArray.Length);
                    crStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    DecryptedStream.Position = 0;
                    byte[] output = new byte[DecryptedStream.Length];
                    DecryptedStream.Read(output, 0, (int)DecryptedStream.Length);
                    crStream.Close();
                    DecryptedStream.Close();
                    return encoder.GetString(output);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is although in DecryptTDES an exception is caught when the data is already in AES, the outer exception is also triggered which I do not want.

Maybe I am going about this wrong...is there a better way to do this? I cannot manipulate the DB tables or anything.

Comment: This is not answering your question, but you should not be using a "password" as a cryptographic key.  There are functions ("password based key derivation functions") that convert passwords into keys, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to address your issue would be to create another table, and copy AES encrypted data into it. This way, if the connection dies, you can simply resume based on how many records have been transferred. And when you are done, you can rename the tables.

You could also add a boolean (or bit) column to your table with a default value of `FALSE` and set it to `TRUE` for each row after cipher operations.

Comment: This is true, but just right now its not that viable for me. Is there anyway that the inner try/catch won't trigger the outer?

Comment: @gti303 What is the exception caught in your outer catch statement?

Comment: throw ex; displays "Bad Data". Happens here "crStream.Write(cypherTextBArray, 0, cypherTextBArray.Length);"

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data

Comment: So I just changed the inner catch to catch  (CryptographicException ex). It catches it...but the outer one still gets triggered :(